How to use git between local repositories (or equivalent solution)
I have a remote website "Remote" (remote.com) and two local directories, "Localhost" (/var/www/html) to serve pages locally (the webpage that appears when visiting "localhost") and "Dev" (~/dev/remote/) where actual code is written.
If I edit Dev's index.php and I want to test it on Localhost then I have to cp ~/dev/remote/index.php /var/www/html/index.php. At the very least I should be able to "push" changes, that is, overwrite given a newer modification date.
As I was writing this I found cp -ur A B which does most of the job I'm asking for: it overwrites destination files/folders with a matching filename but an older modification date than the source file/folder. However, it doesn't handle discovery of source files, it relies on me to specify them all. I can glob *.php but that misses *.css and so on. And I need to be able to say "don't update backups (files in backups/)" and "don't update dotfiles" and so on - I essentially need a .gitignore. (A whitelist solution is welcome too, I'm okay specifying .php or **/.php once in a text file.)
So: is there any way to use git locally the way I'm imagining? Or, is there a solution that emulates the features of git that I'm looking for?

If your model already has /var/www/html as a clone of the remote, you can add a second remote to it, pointing to your sandbox in ~/dev/remote, and you can fetch from that, and then a git checkout of the commit you want to test should do the trick.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849308/how-can-i-pull-push-from-multiple-remote-locations , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+push+multiple+remotes

@phd were you pointing to something specific or trying to say this is a redundant question? Multiple remotes doesn't answer this.

@JohnP Multiple remotes is exactly what you want. You want to push from A to remote.com and from A to B.

The way I'd do it is to have a single git repository, with three branches: dev, test and prod. When you've worked on something in ~/dev/remote/, you commit those changes to the dev branch. Then, you merge dev into test and trigger a pull of the test branch checked out under /var/www/html. Or, to make it even simpler, only have the test branch checked out in both directories, make a commit in your development directory and then git pull in your testing directory.
When you're done with testing, and want the changes on your remote server, merge the commits to prod and pull them there.
Simply put, if you're working with git, you shouldn't be manually copying files from one repo to another. You should be working with branches and just committing what you want, and pulling the commits where you need them.

The remote is not a git installation. The remote is just a server with linux running on it, with no git installed and no way to install it. I used sftp to download everything into dev/remote and I'll be using sftp to upload from ~/dev/remote when I'm satisfied with how it runs copied into /var/www/html. Does that explain everything?

So, the remote (production) server is just a static "deployment" of the code being worked on, and tracked in git. That doesn't really change anything about either my suggestion, or the other suggestion you got using multiple git remotes. If you use git to work on your code in a branch in dir A, then making a commit and pulling that from the same branch in dir B is equivalent to copying the files from A to B.
